# Finding output of watch [script.py] command that I already ran

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh

Couple days ago I ran script using watch:
**watch -c -n 300 python3 some_script.py**

Did not thought that I would like to have possibility to look at the log of this and I did not redirected the output to a separate log.txt file.

Is there any possibility that I can look the output up?
The watch command is still running and the session is active.

I wasn't able to find any solution for this, but maybe I did not look hard enough. If so - sorry.

Best regards,
matmakonen

Comment: There is no historic logs made by watch and so this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

use an external command witch is tee.

so your final  command should be :

```
watch -c -n 300 python3 some_script.py | tee log.txt
```

Comment: Hi MyTricker, thanks for the response. The thing is that I would like to see the output that was created i.e. yesterday. I will definitely change the watch command I'm running for the future though - as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

as @RamanSailopal mentioned, There are no historic logs saved. But if you want to change files in the future, you do not necessarily have to use the external packages. You can use `&>` or `>>` or `>`.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635065/what-is-the-differences-between-and-21) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382793/whats-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-command) for more details.